# Update one(or more) field of a member (registered on a website) using Servlets, JSPs , EJBs

Tags: mysql, jsp, netbeans, jdbc, ejb

I am working on a website program of a 'carhiring agency'

A user can register (done) - using Servlet & Jsp page
Login if already a member(done) - using java bean , servlet and jsp
Make a booking (done)
Delete a booking (done)

I am using netbeans IDE together with mysql(tables : cars, bookings, members) and am connecting from webpages to MYSQL via JDBC. Now i got a little stuck on this part of the task:

Update his/her account (i.e. details)

why? thought of different alternatives such as asking the user to enter username, then displaying the record with member's details , presenting checkboxes so that the user checks the fields he/she wants to change then use the normal query in servlet to update the database. However this doesnt seem to me as the best or 'nicest' option.

I would like to display the 'same' webpage as for the register with the textboxes already populated,(so if the user entered 'Maria' as name, the text box will already have Maria) so that they can be edited there and then and upon pressing submit the record for that particular member is updated. Do i have to use Session methods (.setAttribute etc) to keep the username of the member then display the information in textbox using String uname request.getParameter("username").toString(); (for example)

How would you go about doing this ? Opinions and code snippets are much appreciated

Thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Just let JSP generate the HTML accordingly that all those values are prefilled, preselected and prechecked. In the belows examples, I'll assume you've the currently logged-in user available as `${user}`.

For input elements, just print the `value` attribute:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value="${fn:escapeXml(user.username)}" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="${fn:escapeXml(user.email)}" />
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="${fn:escapeXml(user.firstname)}" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="${fn:escapeXml(user.lastname)}" />
```

*(the `fn:escapeXml()` is very important here as it prevents possible [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) holes)*

For dropdowns, just conditionally print the `selected` attribute on the `<option>`:

```html
<select name="country">
    <c:forEach items="${data.countries}" var="country">
        <option value="${country.code}" ${user.countryCode == country.code ? 'selected' : ''}>${country.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

For radiobuttons and checkboxes, just to conditionally print the `checked` attribute:

```html
<c:forEach items="${data.genders}" var="gender">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="${gender.id}" ${user.genderId == gender.id ? 'checked' : ''}" /> ${gender.description}
</c:forEach>
```

Collecting the submitted values should happen the same way. The only difference is that you don't need to create a new user, but just update the currently logged-in user as available by `${user}`.

Comment: Thanks for opinion so in my regestration page tried to write this down: TR>
<TD> <FONT SIZE=3><b>Username</b></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="username" id="username" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.username)}">

</FONT> </TD>
</TR>

Comment: but an error was marked in ${fn.escape .... so i looked up what to import or add at the top so that it is recognized and found this <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>....which i dont believe is correct due to the url.... what am I supposed to put at the top ?? thanks